# Is there any step by step tutorial on how to implement Windows Authentication with IdentityServer4 and Http.sys?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, authorization, windows-authentication, identityserver4

So I am trying to implement an IdentityServer4 for my Project. I followed the instructions I found in the documentation and other sources to setup a very basic IdSrv.
I am still struggling with how I can implement an IdSrv which accepts Windows Credentials from client and authenticate using IdSrv.

Until now I have not found anything which helps. Everything seems to be too complex. Among the IdSrv.Samples are some clues on how to achieve this, but still can't figure out the right way.

Or maybe I understood all the idea false?

Any help and tip would be appreciated.

PS. I am not using IIS or IISIntegration.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation on how to implement this is at [Windows Authentication](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/windows.html)